# Intuition of convex set separation hyper-plane

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-geometry

According to the hyperplane separation theorem

Let A and B be two disjoint nonempty convex subsets of Rn. Then there exists a non-zero vector v and a real number c such that

$$ <x,v> \le c  $$ and $$<y,v> \ge c $$

for all x in A and y in B; i.e., the hyperplane $$ <.,v> = c $$, v the normal vector, separates A and B

I am facing difficulties to understand what is the meaning of `<.,v>` and how does it represent hyperplane.

Appreciate your insights.

Comment: $\langle \cdot,v\rangle$ is a function that maps a vector $x$ to the scalar $\langle x,v\rangle$. Hyperplanes would be the sets defined as $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\ \langle x,v\rangle = c\}$ for a fixed scalar $c$ and a fixed vector $v$. If the scalar product is the standard one in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the equation $\langle x,v\rangle=c$, is $v_1x_1+v_2x_2+...+v_nx_n=c$, which maybe looks more familiar.

Comment: @mingan. thanks. can you raise this as the answer.

Comment: You can do it too.